# Improve network setup

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, network-printer

My network looks like this:

```
modem -> switch -> router  -> laptop
                           -> other devices
                -> printer
                -> desktop
```

I'm not able to reach the printer from my laptop but not sure why. When I log into the router, I see all wireless devices but not the modem. Shouldn't that have it's own IP address?

Since the router is connected to the switch (a small Netgear 10 port switch) I'm assuming all devices connected to the switch will be assigned IP addresses by the router??

Comment: I'd set it up `ISP modem/router` --> `Router` --> `Switch` --> `then your other devices`.

Comment: At one point I moved the router across the room and I had to switch cables so I can reach it and ended up with this weird setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router assigns IP addresses to the LAN, not the WAN. If your switch is connected to the WAN port, nothing connected to the switch will get an IP address from the router. If your switch is connected to the LAN, the router will not see the modem since it won't have an address in your LAN subnet.

You need to connect the WAN port of the router to the modem, and connect the switch to the LAN port of the router.

Comment: Switch was connected to router's WAN, modem connected to switch. So in practice that means I had 2 separate segments?

Comment: Yes, the router doesn't assign addresses on the WAN side, only on the LAN side.

Comment: Yeah, that solved it, I see the printer now.